# PHP - Removing one array layer

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a simple PHP function that will grab information from a database based on a unique ID:

```
function oracleGetGata($query, $id="id") {
    global $conn;

    $results = array();
    $sql = OCI_Parse($conn, $query);
    OCI_Execute($sql);
    while ( false!==($row=oci_fetch_assoc($sql)) ) {
        $results[ $row[$id] ] = $row;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

So for example `$array = oracleGetData('select * from table')` would return:

```
[1] => Array
(
    [Title] => Title 1
    [Description] => Description 1
)
[2] => Array
(
    [Title] => Title 2
    [Description] => Description 2
)
```

This is fine, however, if I just want to return one record `$array = oracleGetData('select * from table where id = 1')` it returns the data like:

```
[] => Array
(
    [Title] => Title 1
    [Description] => Description 1
)
```

Not only am I unsure of how to reference this (there is nothing identifying the array) I'd also like to somehow change my function so if it just returns one record, it will just be a simple one dimensional array.

I've looked into the usual PHP array functions but can't find anything that'll help, nor an easy way of identifying how deep the array is.

Would really appreciate any help, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [array_pop()](http://php.net/array_pop):

```
$array = array_pop(oracleGetData('select * from table where id = 1'));
```

You will then get one single array:

```
Array
(
    [Title] => Title 1
    [Description] => Description 1
)
```

Instead of an array embedded in another one:

```
Array
(
    [] => Array
    (
        [Title] => Title 1
        [Description] => Description 1
    )
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you - will try to integrate this with some code that works out if there's only one record

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an logic error in your script:

Change

```
$results[ $row[$id] ] = $row;
```

into

```
$results[] = $row;
```

The problem is, that you want to have the Database key value as array key value, but you don't know the Database key, since you don't know what the query will look like.

You could try:

```
$results[$row['id']] = $row;
```

But this only works when all of your results have a Database key named "id".

Comment: Thank you, for what I'm trying to achieve bow this is okay, but it messes with all of my previous code because the arrays are just randomly generated, rather than generated by ID

Answer (score 0):

You pass a $id in the function signature, but in the loop you uses $row[$id], Why? Maybe the error is there.

If you want a sequencial id in your result set, you don't need use the $id, you can uses array_push() function

```
array_push($result, $row);
```

OR

```
$results[] = $row;
```